# Facebook asks for Android key hashes for app that is still in sandbox mode

Tags: android, facebook, hash, key

I'm getting the following unexpected error from Facebook when I try to log in via my (emulated) Android app on Eclipse on OSX 10.9:
"This app has no Android key hashes configured. Configure your app key hashes at http://developer.facebook.com/apps/appID/"

Now on Facebook this app is in Sandbox mode. I've added my hash key to the "Sample App Settings" under the Developer settings.

I've generated this hash key with this command (like prescribed in the Getting started guide of Facebook):

MacBook-Pro:.android macbook$ keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore /Users/macbook/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

Enter keystore password:  android

Why does Facebook still ask me for specific app key hashes, from an app that is still in sandbox mode? And how do I fix this? Is there something wrong with my keytool?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "Sample App Settings" is only so that you can run the sample apps that ship with the SDK.

For your app, you need to add the key hashes to your app's "Native Android App" section.

See this doc for more details: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/#create-app

Comment: Thanks Ming Li, I didn't know that. Funny because it actually worked before. That's why I was confused it stopped working.

Comment: Thanks Ming Li, I also didn't know that. Really funny because it actually workes first time while any app logins. That's why everyone is getting confused when second time it stoppes working.

Comment: i have the same issue its stop working for second time

Comment: If by any means you need to add a Release key hash, check this info: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#release-key-hash